# C++ How to pass arrays to function then have it called to display the values of the arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I Updated the code with the suggestions you gave me! Now i dont know how the heck to call the displayinfo function in main? it says too few arguments passed yet why should i pass arguments when I have another function passing arguments with all the data! I dont know how to call on displayinfo to display displayinfos contents

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void setCourseName(string);
void InputValue();


int main()
{
    InputValue();
    displayinfo( d, b);




}

void displayinfo(int d, array<char, 7> b)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < d; k++)
    {
        cout << "Semester: " << b[k] << endl;
    }

}


void InputValue()
{
    char semester;
    string courseTitle;
    string courseType;
    int credits;
    string lettergrade;
    double gpa;

    array<char, 7> sem1array;
    array<string, 7> sem1coursetitles;
    array<string, 7> sem1courseTypes;
    array<int, 7> sem1credits;
    array<string, 7> sem1lettergrades;
    int amountOFgrades = 0;

    cout << "How many grades are going to be entered today? min 1 - max 7" << endl;
    cin >> amountOFgrades;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < amountOFgrades; counter++)
    {
        bool valid1 = false;
        bool validCredits = false;
        bool valid3 = false;
        bool valid4 = false;
        while (valid1 == false)
        {
            cout << "Enter Semester Number" << endl;
            cin >> semester;
            if (semester == '1' || semester == '2')
            {
                cout << "valid input" << endl;
                sem1array[counter] = semester;
                valid1 = true;
            }
            else
            {

                cout << "Invalid Input! RE ENTER SEMESTER NUMBER EITHER 1 OR 2!" << endl;
            }
        }
            cout << "Enter Course Title: " << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, courseTitle);
            if(courseTitle.size() <= 25)
                sem1coursetitles[counter] = courseTitle;
            else
            {
                cout << "Course Name Cannot Be More Than 25 Characters; Course name limited to first 25 characters!" << endl;
                courseTitle = courseTitle.substr(0, 25);
                sem1coursetitles[counter] = courseTitle;
            }

        while (valid3 == false)
        {
            cout << "Enter Course Type: Regular, AP, or Honors" << endl;

            getline(cin, courseType);
            if (courseType == "Regular" || courseType == "AP" || courseType == "Honors")
            {
                sem1courseTypes[counter] = courseType;
                valid3 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid Input! RE ENTER COURSE TYPE EXACTLY HOW IT APPEARS EITHER Regular, AP, or Honors!" << endl;
            }
        }
        while(validCredits == false)
        {
            cout << "Enter Credits Earned For Course: **Can Either Be 1-4 Credits**" << endl;
            cin >> credits;
            if (credits == 1 || credits == 2 || credits == 3 || credits == 4)
            {
                sem1credits[counter] = credits;
                validCredits = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid Output! Must Enter Number 1-4 For Credits Earned!" << endl;
            }
        }
        while (valid4 == false)
        {
            cout << "Enter Letter Grade; Capital Letter Followed By A Plus + or Minus - If There Is One!Example: A+, A-, A, B+..." << endl;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin, lettergrade);
            if (lettergrade == "A+")
            {
                gpa = 4.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "A")
            {
                gpa = 4.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "A-")
            {
                gpa = 3.7;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "B+")
            {
                gpa = 3.3;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "B")
            {
                gpa = 3.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "B-")
            {
                gpa = 2.7;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "C+")
            {
                gpa = 2.3;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "C")
            {
                gpa = 2.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "C-")
            {
                gpa = 1.7;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "D+")
            {
                gpa = 1.3;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "D")
            {
                gpa = 1.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }
            else if (lettergrade == "F")
            {
                gpa = 0.0;
                sem1lettergrades[counter] = lettergrade;
                valid4 = true;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid Input! Please Re-Enter Letter Grade! Example: A+, A-, A, B+..." << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    displayinfo(amountOFgrades, sem1array);


}
```

Comment: The arrays are local variables of the funvtion   InputValue. They can not be accessed in main. You should redesign your program. The arrays could be defined in main and paased as arguments to other functions.

Comment: `void displayinfo(const array<char, 7>& a)` ?

Comment: @Tristan Roman Like `InputValue` declaration, you must declare `displayinfo`function before invoking it.

Comment: Asking the same question 2 days in a row is not the way to do it. Read the [ask] section and then create a [mcve]. And we'll help you. Proper formatting would also be nice.

Comment: I still dont get how to call the displayinfo() function in main()? like i want the contents of it displayed I dont want to pass any other argument to it....

Comment: Did you tried compiling it? Your compiler should definitely complain about your code and should give you decent hints where to look for the errors.

Comment: I got everything fixed up and Now i dont know how to call on the displayinfo function in main as there is another function passing it arguments and i dont know how to call it .

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestions now how do i call on the displayinfo function to display its contents

Comment: @TristanRoman By the way you wrote `displayinfo` it will display the contant provided by the parameter `b`. You are calling it at the end `InputValue` with the parameters `amountOFgrades` and `sem1array`, so it will display the content of `sem1array`. Is what you want? Well then delete this line `displayinfo( d, b);` in your `main`. If not than please write a [mcve] of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Return and passing arrays is very straight forward. Here is a very *simplified* version.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

std::array<int, 7> input_value()
{
   std::array<int, 7> data;
   // fill array
   return data;
}

void display_array(std::array<int,7> data)
{
   for (int x : data)
      std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int,7> data = input_value();
    display_array(data);
}
```

You can improve this by multiple things. Changing `display_array` to take a const reference instead would be easiest. Make it more general by using templates (or spans). But make sure you understand the differences and learn.

Answer (score 0):

You declare displayinfo after the function using it, which means the functions won't find it.

You should either put the code of "displayinfo" before or declare its head at the beginning of your file (which I'd recommand). I would recommand to do the same with InputValue :

```
void InputValue();
void displayinfo(char b[]);
```

Now there are many problems in your function :

```
/*you're using two parameters of type : array<char,7> and array<string,7>*/
void displayinfo(char b[])
{
    for (int k = 0; k < sem1array/*supposed to "b"*/.size(); k++)
    {
        /*once again you called "sem1array" "b" in this scope*/
        /*"sem1coursetitles" should be the second paramater*/
        cout << "Semester: " << sem1array[k] << "           " << "Course: " << sem1coursetitles[k] << endl;

    } 
}
```

That would lead me to change your function to :

```
void displayinfo(array<char,7> b, array<string,7> c)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < b.size(); k++)
    {
        cout << "Semester: " << b[k] << "\tCourse: " << c[k] << endl;
    }
}
```

So I'd change the call to this function to :

```
displayinfo(sem1array,sem1coursetitles);
```

Concerning the call in your main, you're not giving any parameter to your function, so it cannot work.

Comment: thanks u helped me alot but how would i call on this function in main to just display the contents or make displayinfo do what its suppose to do because i have already passed arguments to it from another function

Comment: You're welcome! I would recommand to create the arrays in your main. Then pass them as references to your function.
EDIT : by your function, I mean the one filling your arrays. This way, your arrays are in your main, so you can then pass them to the functions displaying them.

Sorry I don't have much time, so I might not be so clear :x